# How to remove/uninstall this "PASS BROW" application in Windows 10 / Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I had a friend use my PC and suddenly, I was having to climb over his "account" when it's my PC. He had deleted the icon pic that was associated with my username, etc., so I was just trying to go back, through Google Chrome (He was using Firefox, I think).

Anyway, this "PASS BROW" app popped up, and I began to fill it in, though I don't know why.  I was tired and angry by now.  Then, I cut the machine off over night, try to get back online, and this prompt tells me I used the wrong password and my browser will now be closed for security and safety reasons.

How can I get this 'PASS BROW' off of my desktop? Its a terrible application. I am not computer savvy, obviously, and this has had me locked out of my Google for days now.

I tried uninstalling Chrome, then reinstalling but the same issue comes back.

Comment: Ask your "friend" **exactly** what he did. [edit] your question to include that. Without this information the question cannot be answered.

Comment: So, You can try to disable the extension ??